# Classes in separate files in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, class

I have copied this out of a book. I'm just not sure what to add in the `main.cpp` source file to make it run though.

I know that class declarations go in the `.h` file and implementations go in the `.cpp` file. What would I need to write in `main.cpp`?

I've tried lots of different things but I'm just getting so many error messages.

```
 // cat.h
#ifndef ____2_cat_implementation__Cat__
#define ____2_cat_implementation__Cat__

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Cat
{
public:
Cat (int initialAge);
~Cat();
int GetAge() { return itsAge;}              
void SetAge (int age) { itsAge = age;}      
void Meow() { cout << "Meow.\n";}          
private: int itsAge;
};

#endif /* defined(____2_cat_implementation__Cat__) */
```

...

```
// cat.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.h"
using namespace std;

Cat::Cat(int initialAge) 
{
itsAge = initialAge;
}

Cat::~Cat() 
{

}

int main()
{
    Cat Frisky(5);
    Frisky.Meow();
    cout << "Frisky is a cat who is ";
    cout << Frisky.GetAge() << " years old.\n";
    Frisky.Meow();
    Frisky.SetAge(7);
    cout << "Now Frisky is " ;
    cout << Frisky.GetAge() << " years old.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to compile? What are the first couple error messages you're getting? (Lots of potential problems - e.g. on a case-sensitive filesystem, Cat.h won't find a file named cat.h, missing "}" on end of Cat::Cat(int) definition.)

Comment: What are the error messages you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this part again:

```
Cat::Cat(int initialAge); 
{
itsAge = initialAge;

Cat::~Cat()
```

You're missing the closing `}` for the constructor, as well as an extra `;` after the function header.

On an unrelated note, don't use global names starting with underscore (like `____2_cat_implementation__Cat__`), those names a reserved by the specification.

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing `}` and unneccessary `;`

```
  //----------------------v
  Cat::Cat(int initialAge); 
  {
      itsAge = initialAge;
  }
//^
```

---

> What would I need to write in main.cpp

Usially, as you have pointed out, the `.h` file contains the declarations and the `.cpp` file - the definitions. Then, the `main.cpp` file should contain the `main` function (it's not necessary to name the file, containing the `main` function `main.cpp`. It could be anything.

So, in your example, you can create a `main.cpp` file with the following content:

```
// include the declarations file
#include "cat.h"

// include the header for cin/cout/etc
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Cat Frisky(5);
    Frisky.Meow();
    cout << "Frisky is a cat who is ";
    cout << Frisky.GetAge() << " years old.\n";
    Frisky.Meow();
    Frisky.SetAge(7);
    cout << "Now Frisky is " ;
    cout << Frisky.GetAge() << " years old.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

---

Other notes:

- `using namespace std;` is bad practice, especially in header files. Use `std::` instead (for example, `std::cout`, `std::cin`, `std::string`, etc)
- as you have `.h` and `.cpp` files, don't put half of the implementation in the header and the rest - in the source file. Put all definitions inside the source files (unless you want to `inline` the functions, implemented in the header)
- avoid using names, starting with `__` or `_` - they are reserved by the standard.